# Webpack won't compile typescript to ES5?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am trying to compile my code to ES5. I am using typescript+webpack for this. However even after following all offocial guides and various tutorial on this matter, I keep getting **arrow function** in my final bundle.js file output of my webpack.

here is my webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require( 'path' );

module.exports = {

    // generate source maps
    devtool: 'source-map',

    // bundling mode
    mode: 'production',

    // entry files
    entry: './src/index.ts',

    // output bundles (location)
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },

    // file resolutions
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
    },

    // loaders
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        transpileOnly: true,
                    }
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },

    // set watch mode to `true`
    watch: true
};
```

and here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "target": "ES5",
      "module": "ES2015",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve"
  }
}
```

And here is my package.json file excerpt:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.12",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.0"
  },
```

Output bundle.js file always contains arrow function, I want to get rid of :
[image]

Comment: Is the arrow function coming from an NPM package?

Comment: @Terry yes the dependent npm packages too uses arrow function!

Comment: You will need to explicitly tell webpack to transpile the module to ES5

Comment: @Terry and how do we do that ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydDUm1yPZs0 - this has a way of transpiling using babel/webpack - have a look at my comment underneath too.

Answer (score 0):

add taget:['web', 'es5'] to webpack config

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).